# jQuery UI resizable handle hit area / sensitivity / tolerance

Tags: jquery, resizable, handles

I'm using jQuery ui resizable and I (personally) find that it's like a video game to nail the hit area of when you're trying to resize an element.

It seems like the hit area is a single pixel on the edge of the div! WT...

Does anyone know how to increase the hit area / tolerance of the handle so you don't have to move your mouse like a surgeon to grab the edge of your div?

Answer (score 5):

Resizable handles have class `ui-resizable-handle` . You can style these classes as per your conveniences and choices.
You can increase their size, dimensions, shapes etc.
For example:

```
.ui-resizable-handle{width:0;height:0;border:4px solid blue;border-radius:10px;}
```

In this case, you'll have resizable handles of circular shape, blue in color and quite bigger.

```
.ui-resizable-handle{width:0;height:0;border:4px solid blue;}
```

In this case, handles will be rectangular in shape. 
So, you can do whatever you want with CSS with these handles.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/GCu2D/92/

Comment: I've got the size working now, but I need to prevent the handle from moving when using the scroll bar. See this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/kirkbross/Vcz4h/3/

Comment: Add bottom:0 to handler to keep it fixed to bottom

Answer (score 2):

You can pass in jquery references to the handles like so:

```
$('#elementResizable').resizable({
    handles: {
        'n': '#ngrip',
        'e': '#egrip',
        's': '#sgrip',
        'w': '#wgrip'
    }
});
```

[Demo that I found](http://jsfiddle.net/j2JU6/256/)

Comment: How do I stop the handle from moving when you use the scroll bar? Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kirkbross/Vcz4h/3/